# SSAS named calculation referencing another table

Tags: ssas, calculation, named

I'm doing a multidimensional analysis in the SSAS VS tool. I have two tables, animal animal_intake. Animal is identified with `animal_id` and animal_intake references animal using `animal_id`. What I want to acomplish id to create named calculation in view that will have the information about the age of animal at the intake day. In order to calculate age, I have to reference animal birth date in animal_intake named calculation. Based on solution described in documentation [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/define-named-calculations-in-a-data-source-view-analysis-services?view=sql-server-2017#creating-named-calculations] I have created following query for named calculation

```
(SELECT [ANIMAL].[birth_date] FROM [ANIMAL] WHERE [ANIMAL].[animal_id] =[animal_id])
```

just to get access to animal birthdate. Unfortunately, when I click "explore data" VS presents following error

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

#
```

I don't understand what is the problem - `animal_id` is a primary key of `ANIMAL` table and `birth_date` field has `NOT NULL`constraint. Therefore for given `naimal_id` there has to be exactly one result for the query.

Here are simplified tables from my db.

*ANIMAL*

```
CREATE TABLE [ANIMAL] (
    [animal_id] CHAR(7) PRIMARY KEY,
    [birth_date] DATE REFERENCES [DATE]([exact_date]) NOT NULL
);
```

*ANIMAL_INTAKE*

```
CREATE TABLE [ANIMAL_INTAKE] (
    [animal_id] CHAR(7) NOT NULL REFERENCES [ANIMAL],
    [stay_number] TINYINT NOT NULL,
    [intake_date] DATE REFERENCES [DATE]([exact_date]) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([animal_id], [stay_number]),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
(SELECT [ANIMAL].[birth_date] FROM [ANIMAL] WHERE [ANIMAL].[animal_id] = [ANIMAL_INTAKE].[animal_id])
```

I’m assuming that your table in the DSV is named ANIMAL_INTAKE and that’s the table you are putting your named calculation on.